# PHP Laravel / Oracle compare timestamp . how?

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, timestamp

I am trying to extract from my php laravel some data like this:

```
$x = Carbon::now()->timestamp;
    $data=Notifications->where('happened_at','>',$x)
                              ->where('id_user',Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier());
```

If I enter this sql statement in my oracle database directly it works perfectly:

```
select * from notifications where happened_at > '10-06-2017 00:11:12,000000000';
```

^ this returns correct, however in my php laravel it doesn't return the good rows(returns all the rows from the database)

Later Edit: The where is the problem, I just want to compare the timestamp location in my DB('happened_at') with the current time...I don't know how though

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down your model call code.

```
// first, you retrieve all notifications and assign them to $data
$data = Notifications::all()

// then, you try to start a new query
->where('happened_at','>',$x)

// then, you continue the new query
->where('id_user',Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier())

// and finally, you finish the call
;
```

So basically, you already get all rows at the beginning, and then you try to start building a query that you never execute. (But you can't, since `all()` returns a collection.)

Remove the `all()` and finish up with `->get()` at the end, and it should work. (Although I don't know anything about Oracle timestamps.)

Comment: I don't really think that's the problem because if I change the operator '>' to '<' I get 0 rows, I've also queried like this different things and it worked fine then

Comment: That's because `where()` is also a collection method (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-where), and looking for values less than that will filter _everything_ out by php. If you usually query like this, then it's the same every time: you get everything from the database and then you let the collections handle the filtering. It's not a very efficient way. :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I switched it your way and now I just realized I get errors on where( the compare is bad)